# Implementing event conditions in a C++ state machine

Tags: c++, interface, lambda, state-machine, fsm

I'm using an hierarchical FSM for an embedded C++ application interface. I'd like to use small functions to determine whether certain inter-state events can be triggered, as well as use them to effect changes in the database: however, making a new class with different event functions for each state is daunting, as well as setting pointers to them as callbacks. (we're talking about 300 functions here.)

If C++ supported lambda functions, I'd use them, but I don't have a lot of weight on the project architecture, so I'm reluctant to use third-party solutions that require heavy library integration (like boost) or the inclusion of extra preprocessor steps.

Any ideas?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647631/c-state-machine-design

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you use the Boost/TR1 library, there is support for [Lambda functions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/lambda.html).  Details can be found on the [Boost web site](http://www.boost.org/).

Comment: I'm reluctant to use Boost, as it seems to be a heavy library that requires a lot of integrating into the system.

Answer (score 0):

The new [C++0x standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x) is coming close to finalization and acceptance. It should end up being C++09 when introduced next year. This standard will include [Lambda functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Lambda_functions_and_expressions) directly in the language and obsolete the need for the analogous boost library. The C++ compiler in the technology preview of Visual Studio 2010 already supports Lambda functions per the [Visual C++ Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2008/10/28/lambdas-auto-and-static-assert-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-1.aspx).

Alternatively, you could create [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) bindings for your logic and use tables to handle the FSM as [shown in this wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FiniteStateMachine). This is a very flexible solution that would allow the FSM to be tweaked without recompiling your C++ project. Also, Lambda functions (as well as [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science))) are native and stable under Lua. [Lua coroutines](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CoroutinesTutorial) would also be worth investigating to simplify your FSM implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Qt's [QStateMachine](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/statemachine-api.html)? It might provide some inspiration.