# Python metaclass, execfile, inspect, globals(), namespace

Tags: python, metaclass, execfile

When the following script is run directly, it operates as anticipated:

```
import inspect

__module__ = "__main__"
__file__ = "classes.py"
test_str = "test"

class met(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        setattr(cls, "source", inspect.getsource(cls))
        #setattr(cls, "source", test_str)
        super(met, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)

class ParentModel(object):
    __metaclass__ = met
    def __init__(self):
        super(object, self).__init__(ParentModel.__class__)
    def setsource(self):
        self.source = inspect.getsource(self.__class__)
        #self.source = test_str
    def getsource(self):
        return self.source

class ChildB(ParentModel):
    name = "childb"
    pass

class ChildA(ChildB):
    name = "childa"
    pass

class ChildC(ChildA):
    name = "childc"
    pass
```

The difficulty arises when attempting to run this script through exec or execfile in the python shell or another script. For instance:

```
>>> execfile("classes.py")
```

Runs without issue, however:

```
>>> ns = {}
>>> execfile("classes.py", ns)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "classes.py", line 13, in <module>
    class ParentModel(object):
  File "classes.py", line 9, in __init__
    setattr(cls, "source", inspect.getsource(cls))
  File "D:\Python27\lib\inspect.py", line 701, in getsource
    lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\inspect.py", line 690, in getsourcelines
    lines, lnum = findsource(object)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\inspect.py", line 526, in findsource
    file = getfile(object)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\inspect.py", line 408, in getfile
    raise TypeError('{!r} is a built-in class'.format(object))
TypeError: <module '__builtin__' (built-in)> is a built-in class
```

This results in an error, which is confusing given dictionaries are accepted for the global namespace argument of execfile. But:

```
>>> execfile("classes.py", globals())
```

Again, runs without issue, though:

```
>>> ns = dict(globals())
>>> execfile("classes.py", ns)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "classes.py", line 13, in <module>
    class ParentModel(object):
  File "classes.py", line 9, in __init__
    setattr(cls, "source", inspect.getsource(cls))
  File "D:\Python27\lib\inspect.py", line 701, in getsource
    lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\inspect.py", line 690, in getsourcelines
    lines, lnum = findsource(object)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\inspect.py", line 526, in findsource
    file = getfile(object)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\inspect.py", line 408, in getfile
    raise TypeError('{!r} is a built-in class'.format(object))
TypeError: <module '__builtin__' (built-in)> is a built-in class
```

From the traceback, its related to inspect, however it should error on execfile("classes.py") or execfile("classes.py", globals()) as well.

So, in terms of this error, how is dict(globals()) != globals() and why does this cause this error ?

EDIT: Reader should refer to both Martijn Pieters and Lennart Regebro answers for a complete picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute a python file with `execfile()` you are executing it in the *current* namespace. The REPL namespace is a built-in module:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules['__main__']
<module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

which means there is *no* sourcefile for `inspect.getsource()` to retrieve:

```
>>> sys.modules['__main__'].__file__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getfile(sys.modules['__main__'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 403, in getfile
    raise TypeError('{!r} is a built-in module'.format(object))
TypeError: <module '__main__' (built-in)> is a built-in module
```

Your next problem is that because you use `execfile` the *module* set for your code is always going to be wrong. `inspect.getsource()` cannot determine where you defined the code, as `execfile()` bypasses the normal import mechanisms:

```
$ cat test.py
execfile('classes.py')
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    execfile('classes.py')
  File "classes.py", line 13, in <module>
    class ParentModel(object):
  File "classes.py", line 9, in __init__
    setattr(cls, "source", inspect.getsource(cls))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 701, in getsource
    lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 690, in getsourcelines
    lines, lnum = findsource(object)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 564, in findsource
    raise IOError('could not find class definition')
IOError: could not find class definition
```

At no point does your code work with `execfile('classes.py', globals())` unless you run it directly *from* a file that has the same source code. On some platforms it may appear to work because `execfile` ends up triggering code that sets the `__file__` attribute of the current module.

The only way you actually make this work is to

- Create a fake module object in `sys.modules` and give it a `__file__` attribute that points to `classes.py`.
- Pass in a namespace to `execfile()` that sets `__name__` to match the fake module object.

Demo:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import types
>>> sys.modules['fake_classes'] = types.ModuleType('fake_classes')
>>> sys.modules['fake_classes'].__file__='classes.py'
>>> ns = {'__name__': 'fake_classes'}
>>> execfile('classes.py', ns)
>>> >>> ns.keys()
['__module__', 'ChildA', '__builtins__', 'inspect', '__package__', 'met', 'ChildB', 'ChildC', 'ParentModel', '__name__', 'test_str']
```

Just to make it explicit, creating a copy of `globals()` only prevents `execfile()` from modifying your current module namespace (or your REPL namespace). There is otherwise no difference between the dictionaries being passed to `execfile()`.

Comment: In fact, it does not. If you create a second file, and call `execfile('classes.py', globals())` you will find that it raises an error.

Comment: Sorry, Martijn, I believe you are incorrect. The problem is when the namespace it's executed in is not the `globals()` of the class module. This happens if you run it in the interpreter, or execfile it and pass in a namespace. But if you do not pass in a namespace, it works.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: I did **not** pass in a namespace. I tested this with  PDB and ran through the various scenarios. Providing a namespace always sets `ParentModel.__module__` to `__builtin__`, whatever you set in that namespace.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: I included the `test.py` script to test this.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: Python 2.7.5 here, on Mac.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32888/discussion-between-lennart-regebro-and-martijn-pieters)

Comment: Yes, but on different platforms. There is some funny edge-case here, clearly. It's also to some extent moot, as `execfile()` is gone in Python 3.

Comment: Its gone !?!?! Surely not without replacement ?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, just to confirm, the inspect operates on a module level and using execfile sidesteps this?

Comment: @dilbert: Yeah, exec(open(filename)), which works in Python 2 as well.

Comment: @dilbert: The replacement is to use `compile()` yourself then `exec()` on the compiled object. Or pass the open file object to `exec()`.

Comment: @dilbert: `inpect()` looks for the module on the inspected class, and when using `execfile` that module name is inherited from the current namespace.

Comment: But as per the example, passing execfile a namespace with __name__ defined overrides this?

Comment: @dilbert: `__name__` is the name of the module the code *thinks* is being used.

Answer (score 1):

This issue isn't that `dict(globals()) != globals()`, because it is. The issue here is that the `globals()` in the context you execute `execfile()` is not the same `globals()` as in your `classes.py`.

When you pass in a namespace you replace the namespace that would otherwise be created. If you pass in a namespace, you'll get one created for you for the `classes` module. This means that `__main__` will be the classes.py file. However, when you pass in the namespace of the file where `execfile()` is called, that namespace will be used instead, and `__main__` will be that module.

That leads to inspect failing to find the class definition in the source code, because it's looking in the wrong file.

If you pass in an empty namespace, it will not find a `__main__` at all, and the class will be assumed to be a builtin, with no source available, and an error to that effect will be raised.

In summary, the mistake you make here is to think of `globals()` and being global to the interpreter, when it's in fact global to the module.

From discussions with Marjtin, it's clear that things work slightly differently on OS X. That means you can  not rely on this working even if you don't pass in a namespace.

And that then leads to the question of why you are doing this, and what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve something awfully, awfully dodgy. But the help is much appreciated.

Comment: @dilbert: The point being is that there probably is a better way.

Comment: Well, I understand its best to go for approaches more congruent with the system you're operating under, but this is a bit different. I'm intending to extend upon: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907186/python-model-inheritance-and-order-of-model-declaration.

Comment: @dilbert: Well, as long as you do it for fun and learning. :-)