# ordering classes in a a python module

Tags: python

I have the following three classes in a python file , obviously I get an error at customerOrder (line 3) since its not defined yet - the classes are generated using a uml to python tool (witchcraftmda) , is there a python module to auto order the classes so the dependent classes are moved up automagically - or any other python tricks (I am a newbie).

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    displayName = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    customerOrder = CustomerOrderSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer


class CustomerOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    displayName = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    customer = CustomerLookupSerializer

    orderItems = OrderItemSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomerOrder


class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    displayName = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    customerOrder = CustomerOrderLookupSerializer
    product = ProductLookupSerializer


    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
```

Comment: There are a discussion about inheritance here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16907186/5510499. And there is one solution: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28254/out-of-order-class-resequencer that works, when a superClass is declared after Class.

Comment: Thanks a lot vadim , hopefully this will work in my use case as well