# Dynamic inheritance in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

Say I have 2 different implementations of a class

```
class ParentA:
    def initialize(self):
        pass

    def some_event(self):
        pass

    def order(self, value):
        # handle order in some way for Parent A


class ParentB:
    def initialize(self):
        pass

    def some_event(self):
        pass

    def order(self, value):
        # handle order in another for Parent B
```

How can I dynamically let some 3rd class inherit from either `ParentA` or `ParentB` based on something like this?

```
class MyCode:
    def initialize(self):
        self.initial_value = 1

    def some_event(self):
        # handle event
        order(self.initial_value)


# let MyCode inherit from ParentA and run
run(my_code, ParentA)
```

Comment: I reopened the question becaused the dup was about changing the class of an instance after creation, and this question is about creating *classes* with different base classes.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Simply store the class-object in a variable (in the example below, it is named `base`), and use the variable in the base-class-spec of your `class` statement.

```
def get_my_code(base):

    class MyCode(base):
        def initialize(self):
          ...

    return MyCode

my_code = get_my_code(ParentA)
```

Comment: Smart and Simple. Thanks

Comment: Depending on how often you call `get_my_code` with the same argument, this will create a lot of essentially identical but distinct classes. Some sort of memoization would be good.

Comment: FYI.... if anyone requires to have multiple parent classes (e.g. ParentA, ParentB both in above case), then you can use `base` to be a list of parent Classes, and then do `class MyCode(*base):`...... while instantiating, use: `my_code = get_my_code([ParentA, ParentB])`

Comment: Incorporating these comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66815839/5122790

Answer (score 11):

Also, you can use `type` builtin. As callable, it takes arguments: `name, bases, dct` (in its simplest form).

```
def initialize(self):
    self.initial_value = 1

def some_event(self):
    # handle event
    order(self.initial_value)

subclass_body_dict = {
    "initialize": initialize,
    "some_event": some_event
}

base_class = ParentA # or ParentB, as you wish

MyCode = type("MyCode", (base_class, ), subclass_body_dict)
```

This is more explicit than snx2 solution, but still - I like his way better.

PS. of course, you dont have to store base_class, nor subclass_body_dict, you can build those values in `type()` call like:

```
MyCode = type("MyCode", (ParentA, ), {
        "initialize": initialize,
        "some_event": some_event
    })
```

Comment: Filip, when I use `type()` the parent will only have the methods as given in the 3rd argument. Any way to keep its methods and only override those given in the 3rd argument?

Comment: Ok I figured it out. Just add the child class to the tuple.

Comment: I'm stuck in a situation where apparently all of my bases are old style classes. ("a new-style class can't have only classic bases"). Or I'm in too deep with metaclasses. d'oh!

Comment: It sounds like a material for distinct question. Would you ask one on SO, link it here, please, I'll try to answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66815839/2668831) implementing the memoisation suggestion for [shx2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21060094/2668831), I'd prefer to use a [memoize decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1988826/2668831) (the end result is still a class but it's clearer to me that the function is the interface), and also use `setdefault` to simplify adding to the memo dict, and do not convert the names to string but use the tuple `bases` itself as the key, simplifying the code to:

```py
class Memoize:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        self.memo = {}

    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self.memo.setdefault(args, self.f(*args))

class ParentA:
    def initialize(self):
        pass


class ParentB:
    def initialize(self):
        pass


@Memoize
def get_my_code(base):

    class MyCode(base):
        def initialize(self):
          pass

    return MyCode

a1 = get_my_code(ParentA)
a2 = get_my_code(ParentA)
b1 = get_my_code(ParentB)

print(a1 is a2) # True
print(a1 is b1) # False
```

(Not a good example as the code provided doesn't actually do anything other than overwrite the parent class's `initialize` method...)

Comment: StackOverflow is awesome. Just stumbled upon this very problem again just to find a Stackoverflow question that I answered myself, just to then find that somebody even improved upon my answer! Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Just as a quick copy-and-paste-ready snippet, I've added the comments from [shx2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21060094/2668831) to create this (memoized with a `created_classes` dict attribute, so that the classes created by successive identical calls with the same class will give identical classes):

```py
class ParentA:
    val = "ParentA"

class ParentB:
    val = "ParentB"

class DynamicClassCreator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.created_classes = {}
    def __call__(self, *bases):
        rep = ",".join([i.__name__ for i in bases])
        if rep in self.created_classes:
            return self.created_classes[rep]
        class MyCode(*bases):
            pass
        self.created_classes[rep] = MyCode
        return MyCode

creator = DynamicClassCreator()

instance1 = creator(ParentA, ParentB)()
print(instance1.val) #prints "ParentA"

instance2 = creator(ParentB, ParentA)()
print(instance2.val) #prints "ParentB"
```

If you wanted to get fancy you could even make DynamicClassCreator a Singleton: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7346105/5122790

Comment: Oddly enough, if you import ParentA, this won't work.