# dynamic inheritance in Python through a decorator

Tags: python, inheritance, decorator, python-decorators

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060073/dynamic-inheritance-in-python) where a function is used to inherit from a class:

```
def get_my_code(base):
    class MyCode(base):
        def initialize(self):
          ...
    return MyCode
my_code = get_my_code(ParentA)
```

I would like to do something similar, but with a decorator, something like:

```
@decorator(base)
class MyClass(base):
   ...
```

Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

Say you have a class `Analysis` that is used throughout your code. Then you realize that you want to use a wrapper class `Transient` that is just a time loop on top of the analysis class. If in the code I replace the analysis class, but `Transient(Analysis)` everything breaks because an analysis class is expected, and thus all its attributes. The problem is that I can't just get to define `class Transient(Analysis)` in this way because there are plenty of analysis classes. I thought the best way to do this would be to have some sort of dynamic inheritance. Right now I use aggregation to redirect the functionality to the analysis class inside transient.

Comment: What is the point? If ou have to put the base class on the decorator call, you could as well just fill it in as a base class

Comment: The point is that MyCode is supposed to be a wrapper on another class the code is expecting. So instead of using aggregation, I want to use inheritance so that I don't have to redirect calls to the expected class.

Answer (score 1):

A class decorator actually gets the class already built - and instantiated (as a class object). It can perform changes on it's dict, and even wrap its methods with other decorators.

However, it means the class already has its bases set - and these can't be ordinarily changed.  That implies you have to, in some ay rebuild the class inside the decorator code.

However, if the class'methods make use of parameterless `super` or `__class__` cell variable, those are already set in the member functions (that in Python 3 are the same as unbound methods) you can't just create a new class and set those methods as members on the new one.

So, there might be a way, but it will be non-trivial. And as I pointed out in the comment above, I d like to understand what you'd like to be able to achieve with this, since one could just put the `base` class on the class declaration itself, instead of using it on the decorator configuration.

I've crafted a function that, as described above, creates a new class, "clonning" the original and can re-build all methods that use `__class__` or `super`: it returns the new class which is functionally identical to the orignal one, but with the bases exchanged. If used in a decorator as requested (decorator code included), it will simply change the class bases. It can't handle decorated methods (other than classmethod and staticmethod), and don't take care of naming details - such as qualnames or `repr` for the methods.

```
from types import FunctionType

def change_bases(cls, bases, metaclass=type):
    class Changeling(*bases, metaclass=metaclass):
        def breeder(self):
            __class__  #noQA

    cell = Changeling.breeder.__closure__
    del Changeling.breeder

    Changeling.__name__ = cls.__name__

    for attr_name, attr_value in cls.__dict__.items():
        if isinstance(attr_value, (FunctionType, classmethod, staticmethod)):
            if isinstance(attr_value, staticmethod):
                func = getattr(cls, attr_name)
            elif isinstance(attr_value, classmethod):
                func = attr_value.__func__
            else:
                func = attr_value
            # TODO: check if func is wrapped in decorators and recreate inner function.
            # Although reaplying arbitrary decorators is not actually possible -
            # it is possible to have a "prepare_for_changeling" innermost decorator
            # which could be made to point to the new function.
            if func.__closure__ and func.__closure__[0].cell_contents is cls:
                franken_func = FunctionType(
                    func.__code__,
                    func.__globals__,
                    func.__name__,
                    func.__defaults__,
                    cell
                )
                if isinstance(attr_value, staticmethod):
                    func = staticmethod(franken_func)
                elif isinstance(attr_value, classmethod):
                    func = classmethod(franken_func)
                else:
                    func = franken_func
                setattr(Changeling, attr_name, func)
                continue
        setattr(Changeling, attr_name, attr_value)

    return Changeling


def decorator(bases):
    if not isinstance(base, tuple):
        bases = (bases,)
    def stage2(cls):
        return change_bases(cls, bases)
    return stage2
```

Comment: I have updated my question with the actual situation.