# Pass a list of strings as parameter of a dependant task in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to pass a list of strings from one task to another one via [XCom](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms) but I do not seem to manage to get the pushed list interpreted back as a list.

For example, when I do this in some function `blah` that is run in a `ShortCircuitOperator`:

```
paths = ['gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket, obj) for obj in my_list]
kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='return_value', value=full_paths)
```

and then I want to use such list as a parameter of an operator. For example,

```
run_task_after_blah = AfterBlahOperator(
    task_id='run-task-after-blah',
    ...,
    input_paths="{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='find-paths') }}",
    ...,
)
```

I expect `input_paths` to be equal to `paths` but it does not because the rendering happens firs and then assignment, and somewhat the template rendering converts the `xcom_pull` return to a *stringified* list (and thereafter my `AfterBlahOperator` inserts assigns that as the value of an element in a JSON.

I tried concatenating the `paths` into one string separated by some separator and pushing that to the XCom and then splitting that back when pulling from the XCom but as the XCom gets rendered first, I get, either that *stringified* list when the `split` function is called inside the template or the original concatenated string of `paths` if the `split` function is applied to the parameter (as in `"{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='find-paths') }}".split(';')`.

XCom seems to work great for single values as task parameters or multiple values when the extracted values can be further processed but not for multiple_values to convert into 'one' as parameter of a task.

Is there a way to do this without having to write an extra function that precisely returns such list of strings?
Or maybe I am abusing XCom too much, but there are many operators in Airflow that take a list of elements as parameter (e.g., usually the full path to multiple files that are the result of some previous task, hence not known beforehand).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jinja renders strings, so if you fetch an XCom via templates, it's always going to be a string. Instead, you will need to fetch the XCom where you have access to the `TaskInstance` object. Something like this:

```
class AfterBlahOperator(BaseOperator):

    def __init__(self, ..., input_task_id, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.input_task_id = input_task_id
        super(AfterBlahOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def execute(self, context):
        input_paths = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids=self.input_task_id)
        for path in input_paths:
            ...
```

This is similar to how you would fetch it within a `PythonOperator`, which the [XCom docs](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html#xcoms) provide an example of.

Note that you can still support a separate `input_paths` parameter for when it can be hardcoded in a DAG, you'll just need an extra check to see which param to read the value from.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for too much then! But yes, a custom operator with the 'operation' itself is the way to go. I just wanted to avoid the extra code but probably this is a trade off due to using Jinja.

Answer (score 1):

Call `eval(input_paths)` inside `AfterBlahOperator`'s `execute` method. This way, stringified list can be converted back to list

```
class AfterBlahOperator(BaseOperator):
template_fields = (input_paths)

def __init__(self, ..., *args, **kwargs):
    ...


def execute(self, context):
    paths = eval(input_paths) 
    for path in paths:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Daniel Hung's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47060555/5122790), I made a quick factory that allows to "unpack" Jinja-Templated strings into a list for arbitrary operators with minimal Boilerplate-Code (so you don't need to create a subclass for every single operator):

```
def operator_unpackjinja_factory(baseclass):
    class ChildUnpackJinja(baseclass):
        def __init__(self, xcompull_taskid, *args, xcompull_key="return_value", xcompull_attrname="objects", **kwargs):
            self.xcompull_taskid = xcompull_taskid
            self.xcompull_key = xcompull_key
            self.xcompull_attrname = xcompull_attrname
            self.baseclass = baseclass
            assert xcompull_attrname not in kwargs
            kwargs[xcompull_attrname] = "EMPTY"
            super(ChildUnpackJinja, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        def execute(self, context):
            objects = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids=self.xcompull_taskid, key=self.xcompull_key)
            setattr(self, self.xcompull_attrname, objects)
            return super(ChildUnpackJinja, self).execute(context)

    return ChildUnpackJinja
```

The call of this factory can then be used as drop-in replacement for whatever Operator you originally wanted to use, like this:

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery import GCSToBigQueryOperator

with Dag(...) as dag:
    gcpbucket_to_bigquery_stagingtable = operator_unpackjinja_factory(GCSToBigQueryOperator)(
        xcompull_taskid = "my_upstream_task_id",
        xcompull_attrname = "source_objects",
        task_id="gcpbucket_to_bigquery_stagingtable",
        dag=dag,
        bucket="my_bucket_name"
    )
```

As discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66855473), I would recommend to also create the `Memoize` class and add the `@Memoize`-decorator to the factory:

```
class Memoize:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        self.memo = {}
    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self.memo.setdefault(args, self.f(*args))

@Memoize
def operator_unpackjinja_factory(baseclass):
   <content unchanged, see above>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old but for those passing by you can now render jinja templated as Python object directly.

In Airflow you must add to the `dag` definition the parameter `render_template_as_native_obj` to `True`:

```py
with DAG(
    ...,
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
) as dag:
```

From the doc:

> If True, uses a Jinja `NativeEnvironment`
> to render templates as native Python types. If False, a Jinja
> `Environment` is used to render templates as string values.