# GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator source_objects to receive list via XCom

Tags: python, airflow

I would like to pass a list of strings, containing the name of files in google storage to XCom. Later to be picked up by a GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator task. The **source_objects** field is templated, so that Jinja templating can be used. Unfortunately, Jinja can only return a string, and thus I cannot pass the list in XCom.

How can I use a XCom list in GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator?

Reference to a similar question, solved by using *provide_context*:   [Pass a list of strings as parameter of a dependant task in Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47052582/2475509)

The closest solution I've found, which works, is to create a wrapper class and sending the id of the task who posted the xcom like so:

```
@apply_defaults
def __init__(self, source_objects_task_id,
....
def execute(self, context):
    source_objects = context['ti']
          .xcom_pull(task_ids=self.source_objects_task_id)
    operator = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
          source_objects=source_objects,
          dag=self.dag,
....
)

    operator.execute(context)
```

Comment: How are you retrieving the list of google storage objects?

Comment: The `source_objects` field in `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` can have wildcards as well, so if you are just listing out GCS objects and then using `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator`, then you can just reduce this step into 1.

Comment: Retrieving them from another task, which uploads to Google Cloud Storage and returns the uploaded filenames. And thus in XCom. The filenames are a md5 hash, which I think I can  use for skipping upload at a later time.

Comment: Wildcards was an interesting input. I think it will make things more difficult in my case, but maybe if I rather made the bucket unique instead of the files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure how you get the list of Google Cloud Storage objects but if you are doing it using `GoogleCloudStorageListOperator` then you can instead pass wildcards to `source_objects` params in `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` in the same way that you do in BigQuery Web UI:

```py
GCS_to_BQ = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='gcs_to_bq',
    bucket='test_bucket',
    source_objects=['folder1/*.csv', 'folder2/*.csv'],
    destination_project_dataset_table='dest_table',
    schema_object='gs://test-bucket/schema.json',
    source_format='CSV',
    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    bigquery_conn_id='bq-conn',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='gcp-conn',
    dag=dag
)
```

If you want to get a list from other task using `xcom`, you can create a new operator or an Airflow plugin for `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` adding a new param `source_objects_task_id`, removing `source_objects` param and just replace the following code (Line 203 and 204: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/ac9033db0981ae1f770a8bdb5597055751ab15bd/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_bq.py#L203-L204 ):

```py
source_uris = ['gs://{}/{}'.format(self.bucket, source_object)
               for source_object in self.source_objects]
```

with

```py
source_uris = ['gs://{}/{}'.format(self.bucket, source_object)
               for source_object in context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids=self.source_objects_task_id)]
```

and use it as follows:

```py
GCS_to_BQ = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='gcs_to_bq',
    bucket='test_bucket',
    source_objects_task_id='task-id-of-previos-task',
    destination_project_dataset_table='dest_table',
    schema_object='gs://test-bucket/schema.json',
    source_format='CSV',
    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    bigquery_conn_id='bq-conn',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='gcp-conn',
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: Folder and wildcard was a smart solution @kaxil. I'm doing a download of files from an external webservice, from which I do not know the filenames. But I could create a unique folder and pass that on as XCom and use Jinja. Excellent solution!

Comment: Also, the second solution you propose is tried and works well. Will change it to your first tip tho.

Comment: Awesome. Glad that it helped you :)

Comment: Note that you can only pass a *single wildcard* per URI. See docs for BigQueryBaseCursor.create_external_table.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from 2.1.0 the Airflow added [the ability to render XCOM output as native Python objects](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/operators.html#rendering-fields-as-native-python-objects).

Set the `render_template_as_native_obj=True` in your DAG constructor:

```
dag = DAG(
    ...
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
)
```

Because the `render_template_as_native_obj` works for the `PythonOperator` only (let me know if I am wrong, I tested on other operators and nothing works) we need to wrap our operator into `PythonOperator`:

```
PythonOperator(dag=dag, task_id='any', python_callable=_import, provide_context=True)
```

where the python callback function extracts the source objects from XCOM and executes the GCS operator:

```
def _import(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs["ti"]

    op = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
        ...
        source_objects=ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="task-id-of-previos-task"),
        ...
 
    op.execute(kwargs)
```

Because the `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` is deprecated I used the `GCSToBigQueryOperator`.