# How to pass a list as variable to SQL in airflow

Tags: python, sql, airflow

So a python list will render like `["a", "b", "c"...]` which SQL will see as invalid syntax.

I have some python code that sets an xcom variable

```
#tried with () and []
y = ("2020-10-01", "2020-10-02")
kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='refresh_dates', value=y)
```

Then in my sql I do

```
where start_date IN {{ task_instance.xcom_pull(key='refresh_dates', task_ids='prep_dag_task')
```

However this gets rendered as a python list like `["2020-10-01", "2020-10-02"]` which sql can't reconize.  How can I pass a proper sql list? If I create a string like `"("2020-10-01", "2020-10-02")"` it will get rendered as a string and not a list.. so how can I accomplish this?

Comment: could you try the following : `{{ tuple(task_instance.xcom_pull(key='refresh_dates', task_ids='prep_dag_task')) }}`, essentially, changing the list to a tuple which is a valid sql form.

Comment: this should help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47052582/pass-a-list-of-strings-as-parameter-of-a-dependant-task-in-airflow

Comment: @AnandVidvat I get this error `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'tuple' is undefined`

Comment: could you use the format function instead of jinja? so it would transform like  "select * from table where start_date in {}".format(tuple(task_instance.xcom_pull(key='refresh_dates', task_ids='prep_dag_task'))

Comment: @AnandVidvat this is in a seperate .sql file.

Answer (score 0):

Tuple is the way to go here:

```
test = ["2022-01-01", "2022-02-01"]
sql = f'select * from table where date_col in {tuple(test)}'
print(sql)
```

Should be noted this will break if there is only one item in the tuple (leaves a comma at the end). You can always remove the comma if one item is a possibility