# Dynamic inheritance that is pickleable?

Tags: python, pickle, dill

After much searching, the only way I have found to solve my particular problem is to use dynamic inheritance. It is easy enough following the guide from [here](http://alexgaudio.com/2011/10/07/dynamic-inheritance-python.html) and a few other SO questions; most table is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060073/dynamic-inheritance-in-python).

Using a modified version of the **contrived** example from the first link:

```py
def makeinst(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    class NewClass(cls): pass
    return NewClass(*args, **kwargs)
mylist = makeinst(list,(1,2))
```

This works as I would hope but it can't be pickled:

```py
pickle.dumps(mylist)
...

AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'makeinst.<locals>.NewClass'
```

I understand *why* this doesn't work but what I want to know is there a way around it? Is there a better way to dynamically subclass something?

(FWIW, `dill` can't do it either. See [dill issue #56](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/56))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the class in the `global` scope of the module, to do that you need to create a class manually with the `type(name, bases, class_dict)` call

```
import pickle

def makeinst(name, cls, *args, **kwargs):

    # This will be a method
    def foo(self):
        return f"I am: {self!r}"

    globals()[name] = type(
        name,
        # This must be a tuple
        # (cls) evaluate to cls
        # (cls,) evaluates to a tuple containing cls as its only element
        (cls,),
        # Methods, classmethods, staticmethods and all class-level data
        {
            "foo": foo
        },
    )

    return globals()[name](*args, **kwargs)

my_list = makeinst("MyList", list, [1, 2, 3])
print(my_list) # [1, 2, 3]

data = pickle.dumps(my_list)
my_list_unpickled = pickle.loads(data)
print(my_list_unpickled) # [1, 2, 3]

print(my_list_unpickled.foo()) # I am: [1, 2, 3]
```

In another program execution you must call `makeinst("MyList", list)` at least once before unpickling to define the class.

Comment: That does work for what I asked (Thanks!) but I should have added an additional requirement (sorry I didn't think of it). This solution doesn't work across sessions. So if I save the pickle then reload it without having every called `makeinst("MyList",...)`, it fails.  Any way around that? (not hopeful...)

Comment: I don't think that is possible, at least for the current implementation of pickle. To rebuild an instance it calls the `__new__` method of the class and looks for the class by name. You can customize how it discovers the state and what is passed to `__new__` but not how the class is discovered.