# adding dynamically a new parent class to an existing object

Tags: python, inheritance, dynamic, runtime, parent

How can one add dynamically a new parent class in python to an existing object?

```py
class A:
    def doA(self): print('A::doA')

class C(A): pass

c = C()

# class 'B' is created after object 'c'
class B:
    def doB(self): print('B::doB')

# XXX: python magic here, which adds dynamically 'B' to the list of parent classes of 'C'
#      as if 'C' was created like this "class C(A,B): pass"

c.doB() # works
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic inheritance in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060073/dynamic-inheritance-in-python)

Comment: There no good way to do this, and this seems like a fundamental design problem

Comment: @cwalvoort That adds a parent dynamically to a class, not to an instance.

Comment: @Barmar, ah, read it wrong. My mistake.

Comment: This _almost_ gets you there but you'd have to create `c` after modifying the class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539052/how-to-dynamically-change-base-class-of-instances-at-runtime

Comment: @Michoel Thank you! It works! The missing "python magic" is `C.__bases__ = (A, B)`