# Python: can I generically combine base class and derived class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, subclassing

Suppose I have a class `X` and a class `Y`, is it possible to dynamically define a class that has X as a base, but also methods of Y.

```
def combiner(base_class, derived_class):
   return derived_class(base_class) # returns a class

some_class = combiner(x, Y)
my_object = some_class()
```

This is somewhat of a pseudocode, is it possible to make something like this work in python?

Comment: Define "combine". Do you mean that you want to dynamically create a child class of a base class?

Comment: Interesting question, but I think you need to be more specific. What is the expected result - a class with all the methods and fields of the base and derived classes? Should it be an instance of each class (as in (`isinstance(newClass(), X)==True`, same for `Y`?

Comment: The `base(derived)` is also confusing. Usually the derived class builds its parent, this seems more like a mix-in. Are `X` and `Y` actually parent and child classes? I suggest you post your exact problem for more accurate answers.

Comment: Please see my edits, tell me if still unclear. I want to combine the two classes such that the new class has one of them as base, but the inheritance is specified by the other class like in the example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic inheritance in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060073/dynamic-inheritance-in-python)