# Wrap an arbitrary class with a new method dynamically

Tags: python

I have a class A.

I have another class B. instances of class B should function exactly like class A, except for one caveat: I want another function available called `special_method(self, args, kwargs)`

So the following should work:

```
instance_A = classA(args, kwargs)
instance_B = classB(instance_A)
method_result = instance_B.special_method(args, kwargs)
```

How do I write class B to accomplish this?

Note: If I only wanted to do this for ONE class A, I could just have class B inherit class A. but I want to be able to add `special_method` to class C, D, E, F... etc.

Comment: Will you require the use of special methods, i.e. "dunder" methods like `__add__`, `__len__` etc?

Comment: Perhaps you want a *mixin class*, that just contains `.special_method()`.  You can easily defined extended versions of your other classes that add this: `class A_extended(A, B): pass` for example.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I would expect instance_B to function exactly like instance_A except with the addition of a new function. All methods should work appropriately.

Comment: You can also try method in this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/21060094/10798048

Answer (score 5):

So, you are describing a proxy object. Doing this for non-special methods is trivial in Python, you can use the `__getattr__`

```
In [1]: class A:
   ...:     def foo(self):
   ...:         return "A"
   ...:

In [2]: class B:
   ...:     def __init__(self, instance):
   ...:         self._instance = instance
   ...:     def special_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
   ...:         # do something special
   ...:         return 42
   ...:     def __getattr__(self, name):
   ...:         return getattr(self._instance, name)
   ...:

In [3]: a = A()

In [4]: b = B(a)

In [5]: b.foo()
Out[5]: 'A'

In [6]: b.special_method()
Out[6]: 42
```

However, there is one caveat here: *this won't work with special methods because special methods skip this part of attribute resolution and are directly looked up on the class `__dict__`*.

An alternative, you can simply add the method to all the classes you need. Something like:

```
def special_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # do something special
    return 42

for klass in [A, C, D, E, F]:
    klass.special_method = special_method
```

Of course, this would affect all instances of these classes (since you are simply dynamically adding a method to the class).

If you really need special methods, your best best would by to create a subclass, but you can do this dynamically with a simple helper function, e.g.:

```
def special_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # do something special
    return 42

_SPECIAL_MEMO = {}

def dynamic_mixin(klass, *init_args, **init_kwargs):
    if klass not in _SPECIAL_MEMO:
        child = type(f"{klass.__name__}Special", (klass,), {"special_method":special_method})
        _SPECIAL_MEMO[klass] = child
    return _SPECIAL_MEMO[klass](*init_args, **init_kwargs)

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo
    def __len__(self):
        return 88
    def bar(self):
        return self.foo*2

special_foo = dynamic_mixin(Foo, 10)

print("calling len", len(special_foo))
print("calling bar", special_foo.bar())
print("calling special method", special_foo.special_method())
```

The above script prints:

```
calling len 88
calling bar 20
calling special method 42
```