# storing dataclass member declarations into variables

Tags: python, inheritance, python-dataclasses

I am calling a get_unit API that returns a json that contains info about a unit. The API supports sending a flag. For now let's say the possible flags are *basic*, *sensors*, or *last_update* and depending on the flag, it returns data. I can provide multiple flags if I want
I want to read the json into a dataclass, but I don't want to write a dataclass for each combination of flags. So my idea is to make a dataclass for each flag, and do "dynamic multiple inheritence" like mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21060073/21395083).

```
@dataclass
class SaUnitBasic(DataclassFromDict):
    _id: str = field_from_dict(default="")
    last_update: Union[dict, list, None] = field_from_dict(default_factory=list)
    counters: Union[dict, list, None] = field_from_dict(default_factory=dict)


@dataclass
class SaUnitUpdates(DataclassFromDict):
    _id: str = field_from_dict(default="")
    counters: Union[dict, list, None] = field_from_dict(default_factory=dict)


@dataclass
class SaUnitSensors(DataclassFromDict):
    _id: str = field_from_dict(default="")
    sensors: Union[dict, list, None] = field_from_dict(default_factory=list)
```

As you can see, some basic fields are defined whatever the flag like *_id*, and some can exist in different flags like *counters*.

Instead of rewriting the member definition each time (because I might change the default behavior, for example), is there a way to store it in a variable and reuse it like this?

```
_id_VAR =(_id: str = field_from_dict(default=""))
counters_VAR = (counters: Union[dict, list, None] = field_from_dict(default_factory=dict))
@dataclass
class SaUnitBasic(DataclassFromDict):
    _id_VAR
    last_update: Union[dict, list, None] = field_from_dict(default_factory=list)
    counters_VAR


@dataclass
class SaUnitUpdates(DataclassFromDict):
    _id_VAR
    counters_VAR


@dataclass
class SaUnitSensors(DataclassFromDict):
    _id_VAR
    sensors: Union[dict, list, None] = field_from_dict(default_factory=list)
```

I tried writing it as in the second example, but this is obviously wrong python syntax.

Comment: If you want to reuse a field, use a baseclass. So `_id_Var` should be define in a base class that all "flags" inherit from, and `counters_VAR` should be in a different baseclass that only some of the "flags" inherit from. But in general, this is honestly a very weird design.

Comment: @MegaIng I'm starting to feel this way myself, to be completely honest. Is there a better idea or design pattern that could help with this? I've looked around and this seemed the most doable (using OOP)

Comment: I am not really sure why you want to convert the dictionary into a dataclass in the first place. If there are not static guarantees associated with this, it brings you nothing: It's slower, takes more memory, harder to write, doesn't help with name suggestions, ... OOP is a good solution for some problems. This isn't one of them. The OOP solution for this is probably to have a single class that has all these attributes and errors when invalid ones are accessed.

Comment: as @MegaIng puts it: OOP is only good when you know the fields at coding time, and then the tooling can help you, as well as dotted attribute access (like: "instance.counter"). Otherwise just use mappings - "instance['counter']" - you have no transformations to do whatsoever.