# What's the correct way to add new behavior to an existing instance?

Tags: python, base-class

I'm working on a library that provides (1) a **class decorator** to automatically store certain attributes to a file and (2) a **function** to patch the *same* behavior into existing instances.

Implementation of the **class decorator** is fairly simple:

```
def store_instances(path, attrs):
    def decorator(cls):
        class Decorated(cls, StorageBehavior):
            _path = path
            _attrs = attrs
        return Decorated
    return decorator
```

but for the **function**, what's the best way to add behavior from a base class into an existing object? Searching for "dynamically changing base classes" yields [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539052/python-dynamically-changing-base-classes-at-runtime-how-to), but the answers are essentially "don't do that and/or it's not possible". Is there a better way to this?

Comment: Why are you decorating, rather than just using `SpecialBehavior` as an explicit mix-in? And *what* "special behaviour" are you trying to patch in?

Comment: Class decorators used this way have a nasty habit of breaking `super`. . . I think @jonrsharpe is on the right track.  Just have the user mix it in themselves (it's no harder than having them add a decorator)

Comment: "special behavior" = storing certain attributes to a file

I'm using a decorator because it requires less modification to exiting code and I can pass arguments to the decorator such as which attributes I care about and where to store them.

Comment: Could you provide a less abstract example of what you're trying to achieve? It's difficult to make helpful suggestions in such a general sense.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is that more clear?

Comment: It's an improvement, but it's still not clear what the behaviour you are trying to add is, or what `StorageBehaviour` does. Also from [PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) on leading and trailing double underscores: *"Never invent such names; only use them as documented."*

Comment: @jonrsharpe I removed the double underscores; they're not relevant to my question.

Answer (score 0):

This achieves the same effect as the class decorator:

```
def store(instance, path, attrs):

    class Decorated(instance.__class__, StorageBehavior):
        _path = path
        _attrs = attrs

    instance.__class__ = Decorated

    return instance
```