# How to switch between methods inherited from multiple classes in Python

Tags: python

I would like to build a class which inherits from a `dict` and some other classes.

Based on a key of `someDict` (initial dictionary), `Third` class should inherit either from `First` or from `Second`.

Here is a basic example:

```
class First(object):

  def first_action(self):
      print "first_action"


class Second(object):

  def second_action(self):
      print "second_action"


class Third(dict, First, Second):
   """This is not running code
      but, rather, an example of desired functionality.
   """
   if "x" == someDict["some_key"]:
       third_action == First.first_action()
       print third_action
   else:
       third_action == Second.second_action()
       print third_action
```

A desired output:

```
obj = Third()
obj.third_action()
'first_action'  # <- Should print this value if dict["some_key"] = "x"
'second_action' # <- if someDict["some_key"] != "x"
```

For more general case `Third` class, based on the value of a key of `someDict`, should switch between methods belonging to `First` or `Second`. 
If `action` is a method of `Third`, it should switch between `first_action` or `second_action`.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you just write a method `third_action` that has your `if` code inside it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to call a function called action then it will automatically chose which action to run?

Comment: In reality, I have more than one method to switch between. To rephrase it, `Third` should behave as `First` or `Second` based on `dict["value"]`. A chameleon class, if you will...:)

Comment: @m170897017: Yes, you got it right!

Comment: Does Third need to be a subclass of dict? Could you not pass a dictionary to Third's `__init__()`?

Comment: Yes, `Third` is a subclass of `dict`. And, yes, that's what I do: I use 'my_dict = getattr(__import__("someDict", fromlist=[]))` and `super(Third, self).__init__(my_dict). When this is done, I check a key of `my_dict` and . based on the value, I should use methods of `First` or `Second`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### General case

As long as `some_key` can be changed, the inheritance is not what you want here. Despite of the fact you [*technically*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539052/python-dynamically-changing-base-classes-at-runtime-how-to) could make this kind of *chameleon* class, you should [definitely avoid this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Basically, you should explicitly override all *chameleon* methods and call another one within, according to your condition (`"x" == someDict["some_key"]`).

You also may have a look at [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). Your object may store the `action` and apply different decorators according to the condition. Once again, as far as I understand the question, the condition may vary, hence must be checked every single time (and this means you should override all methods that depend on this condition).

You also may want to override all methods that could change `some_key` instead of all *chameleon* ones: it allows to cache the result of `"x" == someDict["some_key"]` while `some_key` is not changing.

### Predefined dictionary case

In comment section you say your dictionary is predefined. In this case, you should just define two different classes:

```
class ThirdA(dict, First)
class ThirbB(dict, Second)
```

Also you need some [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) to choose between `ThirdA` and `ThirdB` for you.

```
class ThirdFactory(object):
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, dictionary):
        if "x" == dict["some_key"]:
            return ThirdA(dictionary)
        else:
            return ThirdB(dictionary)
```

([Factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) also works here, as long as you have suitable class to place it.)

So now you can just

```
my_object = ThirdFactory.create(dict(some_key='x'))
```

Mind that the class of the object *will never change*. If you want it to change, view the first part of my answer.

*P. S. Don't name your dictionary `dict`, that's the name of the type.*

Answer (score 1):

While assigning the function from first or second class you dont need to put parenthesis. And also I dont understand what are you doing in this line

```
if "x" == dict["some_key"]
```

Is dict some predefined dictionary then you should not use the name "dict" as it overrides the default builtin dict keyword. Assuming it is a predefined dictionary (let us name it someDict). This shoud do.

```
class Third(dict, First, Second):
   if "x" == someDict["some_key"]:
       third_action = First.first_action
       print action
   else:
       third_action = Second.second_action
       print action
```

Answer (score 1):

`first_action` or `second_action` are not class methods so that you can not call them that way.
You could write like this:

```
class First(object):

  def first_action(self):
      print "first_action"

class Second(object):

  def second_action(self):
      print "second_action"

# you have to change name of that dictionary from dict to my_dict since dict is the name of a built-in class
class Third(my_dict, First, Second):
   """This is not running code
      but, rather, an example of desired functionality.
   """
   # define a function named third_action to achieve this
   def third_action(self):
       if "x" == my_dict["some_key"]:
           # you have to call instance method this way
           third_action == self.first_action()
           print action
       else:
           third_action == self.second_action()
           print action
```

You can get your expected output through this way.

Comment: What about user `super()` or `__getattr__` to transfer the methods of `First` or `Second` to `Third`? How would you do it? Don't know if possible...

Comment: @flamenco No need to do that. 'Third' class is inherited from 'first' and 'second' class, so you can invoke methods in parents as long as those methods have different names by 'self'. BTW, 'first_action' and 'second_action' are both instance methods, so using 'self' is better.