# Dynamic multiple inheritance in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, dynamic

I'm having a combination of "backend" together with a "type".

Backends: Cloudant, ElasticSearch, File, ZODB

Types: News, (potentially others)

So I'm now defining classes like:

```
Plugin
PluginCloudant (which inherits from Plugin)
PluginNews (which inherits from Plugin)
```

The combined class is then:

```
class PluginCloudantNews(PluginCloudant, PluginNews)
```

Now, I'd like to dynamically allow people to define a Service (which takes a Plugin as an argument).

The service's implementation will only rely on the backend, so it seems like that part of the class should automatically be used.

My point is, I shouldn't have to give `PluginCloudantNews` as argument to the service (since the `Cloudant` part is a logical consequence of being in the `Cloudant` service), so rather the less specific `PluginNews`.

How can I just pass `PluginNews` to the Service class (the type), but still end up with the `PluginCloudantNews` functionality?

Some kind of dynamic inheritance...

It should glue together PluginCloudant with class PluginNews, or other type, which are all defined upfront.

Comment: Inheritance really just provides a model for how attribute lookup will proceed. It may not really matter if the new service inherits from `PluginCloudantNews` or `PluginNews`, as long as `Cloudant` appears as a base class *somewhere* in the ancestor DAG.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Dynamically changing base classes at runtime. How to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539052/python-dynamically-changing-base-classes-at-runtime-how-to)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I have fully understood your question, however you can "dynamically" construct class objects using the `type` builtin. The following two lines produce the same result:

```
class PluginCloudantNews(PluginCloudant, PluginNews): pass

PluginCloudantNews = type('PluginCloudantNews', (PluginCloudant, PluginNews), {})
```

As you can see, `type()` takes three arguments: the name of the new class, a list of base classes to inherit from, a dictionary with the attributes to add to the new class.