# How to change the base class in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance

Say I have following

```
Class A(object):
    base Functions

Class B (A):
   some useful functions

Class C(object)
    req base functions
```

Now I want to create a class which has all the functions from B but instead of functions from A refers to functions from C.
Something like

```
Class D(B,C)
   and when B calls super it should look in C instead of A
```

The way that I am achieving it now is copy pasting the whole class B and just inheriting from C instead of A.
Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Composition can surely solve the problem, but Class B is already in heavy use so I don't want to change it.

Comment: Pretty sure this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance . If not could you specify how is it different?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `__bases__` attribute of `B` class.

Well, it's ugly but it works:

```
class A(object):
    def f(self):
        print("A.f()")

class B (A):
    def g(self):
        print("B.g()", end=": ")
        super(B, self).f()

class C(object):
    def f(self):
        print("C.f()")


B.__bases__ = (C,)
b = B()
b.g()
```

You get:

```
B.g(): C.f()
```

You can use [fudge.patch](http://farmdev.com/projects/fudge/api/fudge.html#fudge.patch) to do it during your unit test.

Note that your question is a duplicate of [How to dynamically change base class of instances at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539052/how-to-dynamically-change-base-class-of-instances-at-runtime)

Comment: Thanks Laurent. I was unaware of that functionality. But I want to create a new class D which is exactly like B only inherits from C. I don't want to change the base of B itself. The objects of B should not see any change.