# Can a Python inner class be a subclass of its own outer class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, subclass

This...

```
class A(object):
    class B(A):
        def __init__(self):
            pass
```

... throws "NameError: name 'A' is not defined".

Is there proper syntax to accomplish this, or must I use workarounds, like this?

```
class A(object):
    pass
class _B(A):
    pass
A.B = _B
```

The prior is strongly preferable.  Thank you.

Comment: 1. That's an inner class, not a subclass.
2. No, an inner class  can't inherit (not extend) its outer class because the outer class is not fully defined while defining the inner class.
3. Your workaround is not a work around, as it doesn't have an inner class. You are confusing subclasses and inner classes.

Comment: Note that in Python there are very few good use cases for inner classes.

Comment: Then I misnamed the query.  So this is not possible with an inner class.  Is it possible to rename this, or is the question invalid?

Comment: @DeepSpace, phrase that in an answer and I'll mark it.  I'll answer myself, otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per OPs request, posting as an answer.

1. That's an inner class, not a subclass.
2. No, an inner class can't inherit (not extend) its outer class because the outer class is not fully defined while defining the inner class.
3. Your workaround is not a work around, as it doesn't have an inner class. You are confusing subclasses and inner classes

Answer (score 2):

You can not do this the normal way and probably should not do this.

For those who have a valid reason to attempt something similar, there is a workaround by dynamically changing the superclass of `A.B` after `A` is fully defined (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9639512/5069869).

This is probably terrible code, a big hack and should not be done, but it works under certain conditions (see linked answer)

```
class T: pass
class A(object):
  def a(self):
    return "Hallo a"
  class B(T):
    def b(self):
      return "Hallo b"
A.B.__bases__ = (A,)
b=A.B()
assert isinstance(b, A)
assert b.a()=="Hallo a"
```

Now you can even do something weird like `x = A.B.B.B.B()`

Comment: Oh good lord...  Thanks for the working example, though.  It clarifies just how backwards one must move to make this a reality.  I'll approach the class structure differently.