# How to access outer attribute class within inner class?

Tags: python

I reconstruct my code to more readable by using class and follow javascript style. The class is about modem device. In below I have 2 inner classes, SMS and Identify. For now it focuss on retrieve device informations. The problem it got error

```
'Identify' object has no attribute 'handle'
```

Inner class can't access outer attribute class.

```
import serial

class Device:
    def open(self, port, baudrate):
        self.handle = serial.Serial(port, baudrate)

    def readline(self):
        return self.handle.readline()

    def close(self):
        self.handle.close()

    class SMS:
        pass

    class Identify:
        def manufacturer(self):
             self.handle.write(b'AT+CGMI\r')

             while True:
                buffer = self.handle.readline()

                print(buffer)

                if buffer == b'OK\r\n':
                     break
                elif buffer == b'ERROR\r\n':
                    break

device = Device()
device.open('COM12', 9600)
device.Identify().manufacturer()
device.close()
```

Comment: Why *would* an Identify instance have a handle attribute? Where do you expect it to come from? Nesting isn't inheritance.

Comment: It is not appropriate to use "javascript style" in Python. Use Python style. Nested classes have very limited use in Python, and certainly not here.

Comment: @Carcigenicate the reason is only more readable. Yes, i need to inherit `self.handle`.  Thats the flow.

Comment: @DanielRoseman If so what your suggest to make the concept more readable in python? Class Identify needs handle from Class Device.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with readability. If you need access to it, then you need to use composition, not nesting.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I try what u said. Pass outer class to inner class. But **name 'Device' is not defined**

Comment: @Carcigenicate I don't know what u means to making it a top level class. Can u answer it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I would push back against the claim that what the op is doing is "JavaScript style" to begin with

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inner Classes: How can I get the outer-class object at construction time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278426/inner-classes-how-can-i-get-the-outer-class-object-at-construction-time)

Answer (score 2):

`Identify` doesn't inherit from `Device` just by being defined inside of it. If you want it to subclass `Device`, you need to explicitly write that:

```
class Identify(Device):
    . . .
```

The problem is though, a [inner class can't inherit from an outer class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39077925/3000206). You'll need to make `Identify` a top level class along with `Device`.

```
class Device:
   . . .

class Identify(Device):
   . . .
```

If your intent was to make `Identify` slightly more hidden/indicate that it's an implementation detail, you could make it """private""" by giving the name a leading underscore:

```
class _Identify(Device):
   . . .
```

This doesn't actually prevent external access, but it does cause IDE warnings if it's imported or used externally, [and causes it to be excluded from wildcard imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles):

> _single_leading_underscore: weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. from M import * does not import objects whose names start with an underscore.