# How to access inner attribute class from outer class?

Tags: python

As title. the class set a attribute value inside inner class. then, access that inner attribute class from outer function. In below, attribute sets with inner function set_error. then, use outer function last_error to access the error.

```
class Device:
  error_info = ''

  def __init__(self):
    self.identify = self.Identify(self.error_info)

  def last_error(self):
    return self.error_info

  class Identify:
    def __init__(self, error):
      self.error_info = error

    def set_error(self, error):
      self.error_info = error

device = Device()

device.identify.set_error('test')

print(device.last_error())
```

Comment: what's ur desired output? test?

Comment: @ranifisch yes, output should dependent what `set_error` function set.

Comment: As already suggested in the comments to your previous question, there is no advantage in defining `Identify` inside `Device`.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I guess not. I think it do what i want. To access attribute and function like javascript.

Comment: @David how does nesting this class help you access the attributes like JavaScript? You can do that without the class nesting. There is no advantage, and it is very irregular.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Is there other ways or python style that can access object like javascript? **device.identify.manufacturer**? is there ways to make 2 object share attribute and function. then use the class like javascript style?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Last day, i try to use PyQt5 module. I feels javascript style when use the module. Set attribute that needed first. Then, call a function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access outer attribute class within inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59129879/how-to-access-outer-attribute-class-within-inner-class)

Comment: @David of course you can access an attribute like `device.identity.manufacturer`, you can do that in partially any OOP language, JavaScript isn't unique in that at all. You can do that in your own code, just unnest your `Identify` class and it will work exactly the same. Just use `Identify` instead of `self.Identify` in the `Device.__init__`. nesting your classes here does nothing useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `last_error` to:

```
  def last_error(self):
    return self.identify.error_info
```

You want to get `identify`'s error. you have initialized `identify` in the constructor so you can use it now.

Comment: Wow, So stupid am i. I don't recognize it. Now i can reconstruct like javascript style.