# Can a static nested class be a child of outer class in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I created a class to store settings for TF-IDF matrices generation.

```
class TFIDF_settings:
    max_features = 5000
    
    class word_level(TFIDF_settings):
        analyzer = "word"
        ngram_range = (1,1)
    
    class ngram_level(TFIDF_settings):
        analyzer = "word"
        ngram_range = (2,3)
```

I would like the attribute `TFIDF_settings.max_feature` to be smoothly passed to all of the inner classes - `print(TFIDF_settings.word_level.max_features)` should return `5000`.

As you can see in the code, I thought that inheriting the outer class will do the job, but it throws an `NameError`.

```
<ipython-input-18-0ddd9158decc> in TFIDF_settings()
      2     max_features = 5000
      3 
----> 4     class word_level(TFIDF_settings):
      5         analyzer = "word"
      6         ngram_range = (1,1)

NameError: name 'TFIDF_settings' is not defined
```

Is there any way to (preferrably implicitly) pass the `max_features` attribute of the outer class to the inner classes?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The outer class name isn't defined until you get to the end of the `class` block, so you can't refer to it when defining the inner classes.

Comment: [Can a Python inner class be a subclass of its own outer class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39077623/can-a-python-inner-class-be-a-subclass-of-its-own-outer-class)

Comment: Why do they need to be nested classes instead of top-level subclasses?

Comment: @Barmar I could make them subclasses, but I thought that enforcing the syntax `TFIDF_settings.word_level.*` would make the code clearer by making it explicit that word_level etc. are different configurations for TFIDF generation. In other words, all configuration should be nested within TFIDF_settings and easily viewable in an IDE.

Comment: Seems like a "XY question". Your question is answered by what Guy linked above. If you'd describe what you want to achieve with that instead, it would perhaps help. Also note that you're jumping between classes and instances, which isn't really helpful.