# Approach to changing python class inherited by parent

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have a class that inherits from two other classes, so:

```
# library_file.py

from foo import A, B

class Base(A, B):
      ...
```

...elsewhere I have a subclass that inherits from this Base class...

```
# my_file.py

from bar import C

from library_file import Base

class MyClass(Base):
      .....
```

I would like Base to actually inherit C rather than B without hacking the original file (`library_file.py`). Is there any way of approaching this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539052/how-to-dynamically-change-base-class-of-instances-at-runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `B` is defined in `foo` rather than in the same file as `Base`, you can patch `foo.B` with `bar.C` first before importing `Base`:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from bar import C

with patch('foo.B', C):
    from library_file import Base

print(Base.__bases__)
```

This outputs:

```
(<class 'foo.A'>, <class 'bar.C'>)
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/KindLovingInfo