# Implementation of Liquid State Machines

Tags: language-agnostic, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Does anybody know of an (open source) implementation of [*Liquid State Machines*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_state_machine)?

Comment: some inspiration maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647631/c-state-machine-design

Comment: @jldupont: liquid state machines (LSM) are despite their name not usual state machines. LSMs are artificial neural networks consisting of Leaky Integrate And Fire Neurons. So material about common state machines won't help.

Comment: Could you point out some links or places where I can read more about LSM? I've never heard of them and I'm interested in them. The links found on Wikipedia don't help out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something for the similar echo state networks: http://mloss.org/software/view/138/

Comment: Thanks. Your link lead me indirectly to http://www.reservoir-computing.org/software which has more resources on Echo State Networks but also something on Liquid State Machines.

Comment: Echo state Network are similar but not Liquid State Machines, see for more explanation http://www.igi.tugraz.at/psfiles/174.pdf 
and 
http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Echo_state_network

Answer (score 1):

There is an attempt to code LSM in [brian simulator](http://briansimulator.org/) (open source-python)

Maybe you will get some helpful hints or Code from here:

[https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/briansupport/kh0QkcHhmNM/VTqaOhhGDBUJ](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/briansupport/kh0QkcHhmNM/VTqaOhhGDBUJ%5b1-25%5d)

Comment: brian simulator is not a LSM simulator,  brian simulator is a general purpose code to simulate different models of neurons and synapses

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you tried the PCSIM: A Parallel neural Circuit SIMulator?
   http://www.lsm.tugraz.at/pcsim/
   It's a very hard to understand code, but its is the original LSM of Prof. Wolfgang Maass paper
2. Open Source implementation C# of Liquid State Machine https://bitbucket.org/Hananel/liquid-state-machine/wiki/Home.

The C# code is improvement of the Liquid State Machines as normally defined by Maass et al (1), by using small world connectivity that make the model less vulnerable to failures in parts of the liquid. its solve this issue by specifying certain kinds of topological constraints (such as “small world assumption”), which have been claimed are reasonably plausible biologically, can restore robustness in this sense to LSM.

For more details analysis Hazan, H. and Manevitz, L., Topological constraints and robustness in liquid state machines, Expert Systems with Applications, Volume 39, Issue 2, Pages 1597-1606, http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.eswa.2011.06.052, February 2012