# Calling functions using an array of pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers, header, extern

I have the following files in my program, a header with certain function definitions, and a program with the body of the functions.

**something.h**

```
typedef struct _foo {
 int id;
 int lucky_number;
} foo;

typedef void (*pointer_fc)(foo *);

void first(foo *);

void second(foo *);

void third(foo *);

extern pointer_fc fc_bases[3];
```

**something.c**

```
pointer_fc fc_bases[] = {first, second, third};

/* body of functions */
```

Note that in the header I had defined an array of pointers to functions, and in the `something.c` program, the functions are associated with every element of the array.

Let's suppose in certain moment I need in the `main.c` program to call all 3 functions. With this, how I can use the extern array of pointers to call this functions in my `main.c`.

Comment: `fc_bases[n](params);` (and the `3` is not needed in the `extern` decl.)

Comment: The question about the function without parameters was irrelevant to the problem itself, so I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function pointers are automatically dereferenced when you call them, so it's as simple as

```
foo f;
fc_bases[0](&f);
fc_bases[1](&f);
fc_bases[2](&f);
```

Comment: Both answers solve my question, but the `main.c` program had declared the structure this way, so it was easier to implement.

Comment: If you want some reading practice with function-pointers, I've got some example code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635851/real-world-use-of-x-macros/6636596#6636596) that puts them in an array indexed by an `enum`, tied together with macros. I've also got them in arrays of structs for a finite-state machine [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647631/c-state-machine-design/6758622#6758622).

Answer (score 1):

If `f1` is declared as follows as a structure pointer variables of the structure `foo`,

```
foo *f1;
```

Then you can call the functions first() and second() as follows,

```
pointer_fc fc_bases[] = {first, second};

(*fc_bases[0])(f1);

(*fc_bases[1])(f1);
```